# updating range of for loop with button

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with an uncertain amount of lables with a for loop.
the number of lables should be changable with a func triggered by a button. 
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *


def change1():
    print(days)
    in1 = input('how many days?')
    for a in range(0, len(days)):
        days.remove(days[0])
    for a in range(0, int(in1)):
        in2 = input('type in another day:  ')
        days.append(in2)
    krofl = (days[0], '-', days[len(days)-1])
    firstlast.set(krofl)

Fenster = Tk()
Fenster.title("some title")
Fenster.minsize(width=800, height=900)
Fenster.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

presetdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']

days = []

for a in range(0, len(presetdays)):
    days.append(presetdays[a])

firstlast = StringVar()
firstlast.set(str("preset value"))

lab1_1 = Label(Fenster, text='Zeitspanne:')
lab1_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

lab1_2 = Label(Fenster, textvariable = firstlast)
lab1_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

but1 = Button(Fenster, text='Change', command=change1)
but1.grid(row=0, column=2)


for a in range(0, len(days)):
    karamel = Label(Fenster, text = days[a])
    karamel.grid(row=a, column=6)

Fenster.mainloop()
```

My problem is that the list of lables will be mon, tue..... even after pressing the button & changing the days list.
I have tried the following:

```
number_days = IntVar()
number_days.set(7)
```

and adding this in def change1:

```
sth = int(len(days))
number_days.set(sth)
```

and changing the for loop in the end to this:

```
for a in range(0, number_days):
karamel = Label(Fenster, text = days[a])
karamel.grid(row=a, column=6)
```

but it returns this error:
TypeError: 'IntVar' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Is there any way to get this working so that all the lables update after def change1()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number_days` is not normal integer variable. It is object `IntVar`. You have to use `number_days.get()`

---

To change labels you have to remember `karamel` for all Labels on the list (for example `all_labels`) and then use `all_labels[number].config(text='new text')` or all_labels[number]['text'] = 'new text'`

You can also use `some_label.grid_forget()` to remove label from grid.

```
from tkinter import *


def change_labels():
    print(days)

    in1 = int(input('how many days?'))

    # remove all old days
    days.clear()

    for a in range(in1):
        in2 = input('type in another day:  ')
        days.append(in2)

    krofl = (days[0], '-', days[-1])
    firstlast.set(krofl)

    # it is simpler to remove all labels and create new labels

    # remove all old labels
    for l in labels:    
        l.grid_forget()

    # create new labels
    for number, name in enumerate(days):
        karamel = Label(Fenster, text=name)
        karamel.grid(row=number, column=6)
        labels.append(karamel)


# ---

presetdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']

# copy list 
days = presetdays[:]

# ---

Fenster = Tk()
Fenster.title("some title")
Fenster.minsize(width=800, height=900)
Fenster.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

firstlast = StringVar()
firstlast.set(str("preset value"))

lab1_1 = Label(Fenster, text='Zeitspanne:')
lab1_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

lab1_2 = Label(Fenster, textvariable = firstlast)
lab1_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

but1 = Button(Fenster, text='Change', command=change_labels)
but1.grid(row=0, column=2)

# --- create labels first time

labels = []

for number, name in enumerate(days):
    karamel = Label(Fenster, text=name)
    karamel.grid(row=number, column=6)
    labels.append(karamel)

Fenster.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you mean changing the for loop in the end to: for a in range(0, number_days.get(): ......?

Comment: but `get()` resolved your `error` problem. Not updated labels can be different problem.

Comment: to change labels you have to remember `karamel` for all Label on the list  (for example `all_labels`) and use `all_labels[number].set(text='new text')`

Comment: not updated lables is the problem that I pointed out, IntVar was a try to solve it. Even thought you resolved the error, my question is not answered :S

Comment: also the list may be updated with def change1 but it wont repeat the for loop that creates the labels.

Comment: it is simpler to remove all labels and create new labels because you change number of labels.

Comment: small mistake - it have to be `label.config(text='new text')` or `label["text"] = 'new text'

Comment: even if you don't want to create new labels you will need `for` loop to remove some labels and another `for` loop to change text in other labels.

Comment: you can assign `StringVar` to every label and change text in `StringVar` but you will need `for` loop to hide some labels (or add new labels)

Comment: edit: only works once! second time it returns error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'grid_forget'
edit2: and found the mistake, in the funk labels.append(labels) instead of labels.append(karamel)

Comment: answer edited: it should be `labels.append(karamel)` instead of `labels.append(labels)`

Comment: yeah that was what i was trying to say xD